# How do I setup an Apache double reverse proxy?

Tags: dns, apache-http-server, ssl, reverse-proxy

Just to make life difficult - I'm trying to setup a double reverse proxy:

```
WWW > Router > Apache Reverse Proxy #1 (443) > Apache Reverse Proxy (443) #2 > Docker Container (Which runs on same machine as #2)
```

Both reverse proxies have FQDNs. I'm trying to use Virtual Hosts but clearly don't understand how to set up the proxy.

The main domain is `example.com` (hosted on Apache #1), and subdomain `office.example.com` (hosted on Apache #2).

On Apache #1 I have to Virtual Hosts setup (`example.com` and `office.example.com`). The virtual host file for `office.example.com` appears like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName office.example.com
    UseCanonicalName off
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm /index.php index.php
    DocumentRoot /usr/local/www/office

    ....
    ....

    # keep the host
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / https://office.example.com
    ProxyPassReverse / https://office.example.com

    ....
    ....
</VirtualHost>
```

My DNS records are at Cloudflare and both `office.example.com` and `example.com` resolve to the same external IP address. The pfSense router however has a DNS Override that reassigns office.example.com to an internal LAN address

On Apache #2 my virtual host file appears as the following:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName office.example.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/office.example.com/html"
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm /index.php index.php

    ...
    ...

    ProxyPreserveHost On

    # static html, js, images, etc. served from loolwsd
    # loleaflet is the client part of LibreOffice Online
    ProxyPass /loleaflet http://127.0.0.1:9980/loleaflet retry=0
    ProxyPassReverse /loleaflet http://127.0.0.1:9980/loleaflet

    ...
    ...
</VirtualHost>
```

I left out the SSL encryption items as SSL transport is involved from Web to Apache #1 and SSL encryption from Apache #1 to Apache #2. SSL terminates at the 2nd proxy.

From the outside I can reach `https://office.example.com` which correctly displays the `index.html` file located at Document Root on Apache #2.

However any other link I can't resolve. I get a 500 error if I try: `https://office.example.com/data` or `https://office.example.com/loleaflet`.

I think I'm missing something with the reverse proxy requests.

Comment: I figured this problem out for http/https connections.  The solution unfortunately came down to the following:  Changed: `ProxyPass / https://office.domain.com
        ProxyPassReverse / https://office.domain.com`  to `ProxyPass / https://office.domain.com/ and Proxy Pass Reverse / https://office.domain.com/`

Comment: Interesting situation. If you found a solution, please feel free to post an answer and self-accept it. Also note how I have code commented your URLs and domains to avoid anyone actually linking them as well as changing them to `example.com` which is the accepted “fake” domain used on these sites for example cases.

Answer (score 0):

As recommended above, I partly found an answer for this question. For HTTP/HTTPS links you need to add a / behind the URL.  So:

```
ProxyPass / https://office.example.com
    ProxyPassReverse / https://office.example.com
```

Needs to be written as

```
ProxyPass / https://office.example.com/
    ProxyPassReverse / https://office.example.com/
```

This solves one problem which I'll accept however unfortunately this doesn't work if you need to ProxyPass ws/wss links.  I'm still looking for a solution for that problem.